# React Table v6 - How do you Create a Separate Row For Description Line?

Tags: html, reactjs, react-table

I want to either have a separate row for the description or have a sub table that is expanded by default.

In plain html I could just make every 2nd line have a column span but I can't really do this in react table.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">Description line</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
 <td colspan="3">Description line</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
     <td colspan="3">Description line</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
 <td colspan="3">Description line</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
     <td colspan="3">Description line</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

In the react table example they have a subcomponent, how would I make all of the subcomponents open by default?

https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/master/archives/v6-examples/react-table-sub-components

Comment: Can you also provide the code of what you have tried so far in React?

Comment: Check this - https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/master/archives/v6-examples/react-table-custom-expander-position

Comment: @ravibagul91 - I would need all those rows expanded by default and I am not seeing how to do it from the example.